# Integrating ctags in vim 7.4 in windows 7, Also QNX Momentics on it

Tags: vim, ctags, qnx, exuberant-ctags

I have installed vim 7.4 in a windows 7 machine. The ctags that comes with it seems to be broken. When I do :!ctags -R . from within vim I get :

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c (ctags -R .)
Input file specified two times.

ctags: cannot sort tag file : No such file or directory
shell returned 1
Hit any key to close this window...
```

In this case ctags creates a tags file that is empty. I then installed ctags from sourceforge And it works.

But I could not find how I should tell vim to use the ctags I just doenloaded.

ctags installed in vim is 5.2.3

ctags from sourceforge is 5.8

I tried:

[enter link description here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html#g%3anetrw_ctags)

```
let g:netrw_ctags = "C:/Users/aslavcd/Program Files/ctags58/ctags.exe"
```

To wherever ctags is. But it doesn't change it.

Problem Resolved. I had an older version of ctags installed by another program and added to Path.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and accept it, so that this question doesn't stay open (or completely delete it).

Comment: Well I have to wait 8 hours to to write an answer to my own question and further 20 to accept it. It really sucks to lose the old account and reputation here :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Silly answer. I had an older version installed by QNX Momentics and, of course, added to path.

Further information:
QNX 6.5.0 puts its unix executables (like ls, mkdir, etc.) in the path, which is aproblem because I then ended up with two ctags executables in the path. In QNX 6.6.0. and later the instalation doesn't put the QNX executables in the path directly but uses a .bat file that is has to be executed in order to have them (like when you need compilation).

Answer (score 0):

Put the ctags path into environment variable PATH. In powershell (administrative) do

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", $Env:PATH + ";<ctags_dir_path>", "MACHINE")
```

The version I have works normally. I don't use it directly but via TagBar plugin.

```
Exuberant Ctags 5.8, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Compiled: Jul  9 2009, 17:05:35
  Addresses: <dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net>, http://ctags.sourceforge.net
  Optional compiled features: +win32, +regex, +internal-sort
```

I installed it via [Chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org/packages/ctags): `cinst ctags`. If you isntall it this way, you don't have to do anything else as choco installer handles that. You can also put this into your vimrc such as:

```
if !executable("ctags")
    call system('cinst ctags')
en
```

Comment: I have added it in enviroment but vim seems to use some ctags that comes with it. There is no ctags executable program files\vim

Comment: OK. I found the real problem. I had an older version of ctags installed by QNX Momentics.